# How to optimise a query with multiple subqueries for string aggregation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, sql-server-2014, string-aggregation

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT
    wp.WorkplanID,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ISNULL(ul.FirstName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(ul.LastName, '')
           FROM UserLogin ul
           INNER JOIN Vendors v ON ul.UserLoginID = v.UserLoginID
           INNER JOIN dbo.WorkPlanVendors wpv ON wpv.VendorID = CAST(v.VendorID AS INT)
           WHERE wpv.WorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS VendorName,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + v.PrimaryPhone
           FROM UserLogin ul
           INNER JOIN Vendors v ON ul.UserLoginID = v.UserLoginID
           INNER JOIN dbo.WorkPlanVendors wpv ON wpv.VendorID = CAST(v.VendorID AS INT)
           WHERE wpv.WorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS PrimaryPhone,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ul.Email
           FROM UserLogin ul
           INNER JOIN Vendors v ON ul.UserLoginID = v.UserLoginID
           INNER JOIN dbo.WorkPlanVendors wpv ON wpv.VendorID = CAST(v.VendorID AS INT)
           WHERE wpv.WorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Email
FROM WorkPlan wp
```

It is taking 5 seconds to get data but I want to make it faster.

Comment: Upgrading to 2017 for `STRING_AGG` so you don't need 3 subqueries would be an excellent start.

Comment: You *might* find that forcing your XML to be returned as XML and then using the `value` method give a little performance benefit: `...FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)')...`

Comment: fetching the joined data once and putting it in a temp table might also be a good idea. Might also try to remove the CAST(v.vendorID) thing

Comment: Didn't notice the `CAST`; why are the datatypes of `VendorID` different in `WorkPlanVendors` and `Vendors`? It appears you aren't getting an error, so there aren't invalid `int` values in `Vendors`, so fixing the data type would be of benefit as its makes the query SARGable.

Comment: plus, you might wanna use FOR XML TYPE, so your & < > in names doesn't mangle your xml strings

Answer (score 0):

```
   ;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT wp.WorkplanID
        ,ISNULL(ul.FirstName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(ul.LastName, '') AS FULLNAME
        ,v.PrimaryPhone
        ,ul.Email
    FROM WorkPlan wp
    INNER JOIN WorkPlanVendors wpv ON wpv.WorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
    INNER JOIN Vendors v ON wpv.VendorID = CAST(v.VendorID AS INT)
    INNER JOIN UserLogin ul ON ul.UserLoginID = v.UserLoginID
    )
SELECT C.WorkplanID
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + FULLNAME
            FROM CTE CFN
            WHERE C.WorkPlanID = CFN.WorkPlanID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') AS FULLNAME
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + PrimaryPhone
            FROM CTE CPP
            WHERE C.WorkPlanID = CPP.WorkPlanID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') AS PrimaryPhone
    ,STUFF((
            SELECT ', ' + Email
            FROM CTE CEM
            WHERE C.WorkPlanID = CEM.WorkPlanID
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, '') AS Email
FROM CTE C
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the same query for three columns. You can use a common table expression to join the tables once and use this reference in your query as below:

```
WITH CTE_WorkPlanVendors AS (
    SELECT wpv.WorkPlanID AS VendorWorkPlanID, ul.FirstName, ul.LastName, v.PrimaryPhone, ul.Email
    FROM UserLogin ul
    INNER JOIN Vendors v ON ul.UserLoginID = v.UserLoginID
    INNER JOIN dbo.WorkPlanVendors wpv ON wpv.VendorID = CAST(v.VendorID AS INT)
)
SELECT wp.WorkplanID,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(LastName, '')
              FROM CTE_WorkPlanVendors cte
              WHERE cte.VendorWorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS VendorName,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + PrimaryPhone
              FROM CTE_WorkPlanVendors cte
              WHERE cte.VendorWorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS PrimaryPhone,
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Email
              FROM CTE_WorkPlanVendors cte
              WHERE cte.VendorWorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Email
FROM WorkPlan wp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers do not help as they all query the base table many times.

You can use the following solution to query the base table once and aggregate it up:

- In an `APPLY`, use `FOR XML PATH('row')` to aggregate up the entire dataset into one XML. Add in the commas.
- In the `SELECT`, query each column as follows:

  - `.query('row/TheColumn/text()')` this gets you all the text elements for that name.
  - `.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')` this unescapes any XML encoding.
  - Use `STUFF` to strip off the leading comma.

```sql
SELECT
  wp.WorkplanID,
  STUFF(x.x.query('row/Name/text()'        ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS VendorName,
  STUFF(x.x.query('row/PrimaryPhone/text()').value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS PrimaryPhone,
  STUFF(x.x.query('row/Email/text()'       ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') AS Email
FROM (
    SELECT wp.WorkplanID
    FROM WorkPlan wp
    GROUP BY wp.WorkplanID
) wp
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ',' + ISNULL(FirstName + ' ', '') + ISNULL(LastName, '') AS Name
      ',' + v.PrimaryPhone AS PrimaryPhone,
      ',' + ul.Email AS Email
    FROM UserLogin ul
    INNER JOIN Vendors v ON ul.UserLoginID = v.UserLoginID
    INNER JOIN dbo.WorkPlanVendors wpv ON wpv.VendorID = CAST(v.VendorID AS INT)
    WHERE wpv.WorkPlanID = wp.WorkPlanID
    FOR XML PATH('row')
) x(x);
```

Obviously in newer versions of SQL Server you don't need any of this, you can just use `STRING_AGG`.